# Is it wise to have a single state as an environment object for the whole SwiftUI app?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack, environmentobject, swiftui-navigationpath

I've been looking at different ways to build in deeplinking capabilities for a SwiftUI app using NavigationSatck. Some articles suggest having the navigation state injected as an environment object like below

```
class NavigationState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var navigationPath = NavigationPath()
}
```

We can then inject this into the root view of the app as an environment object and have the NavigationStack be driven by the navigationPath.

By doing this, we can handle deeplinking by appending the relevant paths to this navigationPath and it all seems to work fine.

But since all views now depend on this environment object, just by pushing a new view, won't it redraw all the views before it in the view hierarchy and for a large app with multiple screens won't that lead to performance issues?

Comment: "Will this lead to performance issues" depends on various different things. Just saying "for a large app with multiple screens" is nowhere near enough details to be able to determine that. It is *possible* this could lead to performance issues. Whether it actually does is something you can investigate with Instruments.

Comment: yes it will redraw everything. Notice that Apple uses value types for UI State Management and value types for Data Models in their documentation. Observable has more targeted redrawing.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/restoring_your_app_s_state_with_swiftui

Comment: SwiftUI doesn't draw anything it just computes structs which is negligible. However I wouldn't put view state in an object since it's designed to work with structs.

Comment: @malhal Although `body` is only creating structs and there is no "redrawing", SwiftUI does need to find the difference between the new `body` and the previous `body` to find out what needs to be updated. Would this be problematic in cases where the `body` has a lot of views? I think it would help very much to break the views into smaller `View`s, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yep smaller the better. Apple calls it tighter invalidation.